# Power Query add evey cell with same value as a new column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to join the cells with the same value in power query as a new row.

The data is like this:

[image]

and has to be like this:

[image]

Has anybody any idea for that?

I used the Table.pivot function but, but it seems my solution is not the correct one.

Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"", {{"Date", type text}}, "de-DE"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"", {{"Date", type text}}, "de-DE")[Date]), "Date", "Value", List.Sum)

Comment: Im glad you got an answer that made you happy, but curious what worked better in Sams answer that you removed my checkmark and moved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be via a Merge.  Paste the following into a new query to get an idea:

```js
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtY1MNQ1MFLSUXI0NACSQCJWB03GCaeMM04ZF5wyjqZAwhSLLTjEnXGIA91rYAi2A0hhczMeWWcU2VgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, Type = _t, Value = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Type", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Type"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Date", "Value"}, #"Changed Type", {"Date", "Value"}, "Merger", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "TypeList", each Table.Column([Merger], "Type")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"TypeList", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Merger"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a group on Date & Value columns then change the operation to be a Text.Combine

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Date", "Value"}, {{"Type", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Type], Text.From), " "), type text}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]